# how to scan repos in Azuredevops and filter certain files

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos, git-repo

We are using AzureDevops server and have multiple collections and multiple projects in each of the collections. There are different Application teams working on these different projects and each have their own application specific repos with the Apps specific designs.

So we are looking for a automated way to scan each of theses repos and get the required docs\folders from each of this app specific repos to central location, Either first in a common Repo or then from there to sharepoint site where we can publish the required reports\documents

For example, we have collections called CLT-1, CLT-2, CLT3, etc...CLTn,, Inside each collections we have multiple projects, CLT1PRJ1, CLT2PRJ2, CLT3PRJ3..

Inside each projects there a number of Application specific repos ( like CLT1PRJ1App1, CLT2PRJ2App2, etc..). Each Repos have folder structure and we are looking to dynamically scan all these repos and get the folder (say  CLT\PRJ\App\AAA)
or a specific document inside them to a common repo where we can segregate each of the apps and the corresponding folder\file.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, your demands are quite difficult to meet. There is not an easy way to do that.

Normally, you can try with the following steps:

1. Use the REST API "[**Accounts - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)" to list all the collections you have access.
2. Use the REST API "[**Projects - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)" to list all the projects in each collection.
3. Use the REST API "[**Repositories - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)" to list all the Git repositories in each project.
4. Use the REST API "[**Items - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)" to list all the files in each Git repository.
5. After getting the files of a Git repository, you can filter the required files / folders based on the specific names or paths.

Hope above suggestions can be helpful for you.